# Получение аргумента после сообщения telebot python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Можете пожалуйста подсказать как сделать получение аргумента(в моём случае числа) после ввода сообщения. Я хочу сделать так, что бы пользователь писал например "Привет %число сообщений от бота(например 5)%"
Пока получается так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        for i in range():
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет")
```

Но я не знаю как получить число после сообщения. Надеюсь на помощь, потому что я в этом деле новичок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так

```py
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text.startswith("Привет"))
def get_text_messages(message):
    for i in range(int(message.text.split()[1])):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет")
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверять регуляркой, например:

```
print(RE_HI_NUMBER.search('Привет 9').group(1))
# 9

print(RE_HI_NUMBER.search('Привет 991!').group(1))
# 991

print(RE_HI_NUMBER.search('Привет!!!'))
# None
```

В боте попробуем найти по регулярке и используем число из сообщения, иначе только один раз напишем:

```
import re

RE_HI_NUMBER = re.compile(r'Привет (\d+)', flags=re.IGNORECASE)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        m = RE_HI_NUMBER.search(message.text)
        number = int(m.group(1)) if m else 1

        for i in range(number):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет")
```